# Distance between Saturn's ring material

Tags: saturn-rings

I wonder how much the stones and ices that make the Rings of Saturn are far from each other on average? Is it like just a few meters or kilometers?

I also wonder how thick are the rings? I can guess there is no clear border, but the density over the thickness axis should be distributed normally somehow and in this case, the range that includes the majority (say, around 96%) of the stones and ices could be considered as the thickness.

Comment: There is an excellent link to this query in this answer: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/18463/35206